# New Multisite Network: redirected you too many times

Tags: multisite

I have recently turned on Multisite network for a domain.

I created a network site as a sub-directory.

When I loaded that site's `/wp-admin` I received an error:

> This page isn’t working
>
> dev.example.com.au redirected you too many times. Try clearing your
>   cookies. ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

I have cleared my cookies for this domain but the issue remains.

I have renamed `plugins` to `plugins.temp` and the issue remains.

I added the following to `wp-config.php` but the issue remains:

```
define('ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH', '/');
define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', '');
define('COOKIEPATH', '');
define('SITECOOKIEPATH', '');
```

This is my `.htaccess`:

```
# BEGIN litespeed noabort
<IfModule rewrite_module>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteRule .* - [E=noabort:1]
</IfModule>
# END litespeed noabort

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I followed the advice in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29647392/667903), and changed the given `.htaccess` template by WP Network installation:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) featured/$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ featured/$2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

To this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Works now.

Comment: for those about to `diff`: @Steve removed the directory `featured` from the target of the two `RewriteRules` before the last one. In my case, the whole domain ended up in there (`featured.example.com`) and removing it fixed the problem, too.